# Printing multiple fields of text between delimiters, sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some text where the delimiter column count/order is not same line to line.

```
Line 1 A=123, B=456, C=123, A=456, D=1234    
Line 2 B=123, A=456    
Line 3 A=123, A=789
```

I want to print only the As and Ds within each line, what is the best way to do this?

So the output should be,

```
123 456 1234
456
123 789
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show it! is `Line 1` part of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way, with awk:

```
$ awk -F'[ =,]+' '{for (i=1; i<NF;i+=2) if ($i=="A" || $i =="D")printf "%s ", $(i+1);print ""}' file
123 456 1234 
456 
123 789
```

Comment: Just mention it'll add a space to the end of every line so the OP gets a heads up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[ =,]+' '{
    ofs=""
    for (i=3;i<NF;i+=2) {
        if ($i~/[AD]/) {
            printf "%s%s",ofs,$(i+1)
            ofs=OFS
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
123 456 1234
456
123 789
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
BEGIN { FS=", " }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split($i, parts, "=")
        if (parts[1] == "A" || parts[1] == "D") {
            printf("%s ", parts[2])
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

The input:

```
$ cat in.txt 
A=123, B=456, C=123, A=456, D=1234
B=123, A=456
A=123, A=789
```

Usage:

```
$ gawk -f s.awk in.txt
123 456 1234 
456 
123 789
```

Comment: There is no need to redirect the file `in.txt` to stdin of `gawk`; `gawk` can take input from files via arguments.

Comment: @FloHimself True, changed that.

Comment: Just mention it'll add a space to the end of every line so the OP gets a heads up. Also the 3rd arg for split() is an RE so you should delimit it as such (i.e. `/=/`, not `"="`) for clarity and it makes a functional difference for some characters, and `printf` is a builtin, not a function, so the parens don't do what they look like they're doing when you write `printf(...)` (but should be OK anyway). Finally, this would fail with the actual input file the OP posted where each line starts with text like `Line 1 `.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash. Remove "x=...," where x is not A or B:

```
shopt -s extglob

while read  line ; do
  line="${line//[^AD]=+([0-9])?(, )/}"
  line="${line//[AD=,]/}"
  echo "$line"
done < "$infile"
```

Output.

```
123 456 1234
456
123 789
```

Comment: Your posted output doesn't match the desired output from the question.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions, I actually got an idea for another part of the script I am writing.  For this particular one, I will probably end up using the 1 line awk.

Comment: @HungryFerret You do know you can write any awk script in 1 line, right? It doesn't add any benefit unless you need to pull it back from your history file for editing and even then it's minor...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/\<[AD]=/{s//\n/g;s/[^\n]*\n([0-9]*)[^\n]*/ \1/g;s/^ //p}' file
```

If a line contains an `A` or a `D` variable replace the said variable name by a newline and then extract the following digit sequence placing a space in front as a separator. Finally remove the first space and print out.